# The feature to detect duplicate when asking a question is more efficient than the search

Tags: feature-request

Hi,

In fact, when i want to make a reserch, i pretend to ask a question. And see whats pop up. 
The result are often more accurate that the search.
Indeed, it could be because the key word are more accurate when i ask a question.

Anyway, the search is not so good.

Comment: Me too. I occasionally try the built in search, but it never works. I either use "Ask Question", or google.

Comment: Amazing after 6 years this question doesn't have an answer... does anyone know?

Answer (score 3):

It seems the same way for me...  it seems that creating a new question is much more likely to have results than using the search box.