# Can we have a 'magic' search as good as the duplicate detection?

Tags: feature-request, search, asking-questions, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Related questions in “Ask Question” page is better than search tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/related-questions-in-ask-question-page-is-better-than-search-tool)

I often find myself typing a question with no intention of submitting it, because I'm sure it's been answered before, but I just can't find it.

The automatic duplicate detection is, however, almost always spot on.

So, why not add whatever algorithm it is (bag of words similarity? n-grams? magic?)

(Oh, and guess what - while asking this question, [this (near) duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7550/the-feature-to-detect-duplicate-when-asking-a-question-is-more-efficient-than-th) was suggested, which doesn't ask why the algorithm can't be added as a search option, but suggests my question-as-search method.)

Comment: The duplicate detector runs on ground Unicorn horn. Seeing as SE are good guys, only horn that falls off the Unicorn naturally can be used, putting a natural limit on the availability of the material. (Seriously though - a really cool idea. I can confirm the dupe detector is a work of genius.)